# (Necessary?) side-effect of ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.array())

Tags: java, websocket, bytebuffer

The background here is I'm using a jetty websocket server to connect to javascript on a client.  The server has socket endpoints that you can send `ByteBuffer`s through.

The weirdness is that if I build up an array `bytes[]` and send along `ByteBuffer.wrap(byteArray)`, it works.

If I build up a `ByteBuffer` using `ByteBuffer.allocate` and`buffer.put(..)`, and then send it the same way, the client receives a zero-length message.

The kicker is that if I build up the byte buffer and just before sending, I instead send
`ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.array())`, everything works perfectly!

So, regardless of what goes on in the jetty websocket server, clearly there's some side effect that I'm missing for unwrapping and wrapping the bytes.  I *think* it's all backed by the same data in memory, so I don't *think* I pay much of a cost for this, but it feels *suuuper* hacky, and I'd love to know what's going on here!

Thanks!

Edit:  FWIW, it's unrelated to endianness- both endiannesses(?) work with `ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.array())`, and don't work otherwise.

Comment: Are you `flip`ing or `rewind`ing the buffer before you send it?

Comment: I had not been.  Thank you!
(if you rephrase your question in the form of an answer, I will accept it!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to reset the position of the buffer before you send it, since the `put` methods (except for the ones which take an index) increment the position when called, and jetty apparently uses the position to decide what to send.

You can do this with `flip` which sets the position to 0, discards the mark, and sets the limit to the previous position, or `rewind` which does not change the limit of the buffer, or with `position` which will discard the mark if it is greater than the new position that you pass it and does not change the limit.

`wrap(byte[])` works because it sets the position to 0 and the limit to the length of the array you pass.